# Laravel 5.3 and Ajax Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a gaming website and I'm currently doing the matches page of the teams. In this page I have a Bootstrap carousel to switch between the teams and display the matches of each team, but I have it limited to 5 matches. After that I use Laravel built in pagination that I've made it to work in AJAX. However when I change the page it changes the content of all my team's matches (obviously since I'm replacing `div.matches` content).

How can I do it to each team instead of replacing every team with the same content?

The pagination works correctly without AJAX.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$matches = Matche::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->where('team', $team->id)->paginate(5, ['*'], $team->slug);

// it generates like so.. site.com/matches?csgo=1
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="matches">

        <div class="matches-box">
           ... Match #1 ...
        </div>
        <div class="matches-box">
           ... Match #2 ...
        </div>

        {{ $matches->links() }}

    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(url, function(data){
        $('.matches').html($(data).find('.matches').html());
    });

});
```

Comment: You can flow this tutorial https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax Pagination in Laravel 5.*:

```
 $('.pagi').delegate('.pagination a','click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var pagiurl = $(this).attr('href');
          $.ajax({
                url: pagiurl,
                data:"",
                headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(json) {
                    $('#renderstring').html(json.success);
                    $('.pagi').html(json.pagi);
                },
            });
    });
```